# this error in the console ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validate_docbr'

Tags: python, installation, import, pip, pep

I am making a small project and installed the library "pip3 install validate_docbr". I can use it normally in the console, but when I run an application that imports it, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validate_docbr'".

I just wanted to import this function to my code "from validate_docbr import CPF"

from validate_docbr import CPF >>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validate_docbr'

Comment: It sounds like you have two different versions of python installed on your computer.  What are the exact commands you use to start python, in the case where the import works, and the case where it doesn't?